# Simple Progress Bar to input file

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, file-upload

I have a basic html form with a `<input type="file" />` field:

```
                <form class="form-horizontal" action='helper.php' method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">                      
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="supporting-document" />
                    <input type="file" name="document" id="document" title="Select" class="btn btn-mini" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                    <div id="progress-bar">
                        <div class="progress"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Is it possible to add a basic progress bar using jQuery?

Comment: Take a look here: [Progressbar jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571852/jquery-progressbar-progress-based-on-user-input-where-values-get-saved)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery, there are lots of plugin you can use

for example: http://www.uploadify.com/

as security reason, the javascript cannot obtain the information of the client files

But if your site is going to use HTML5, there is a new FILE API can be used for such purpose.

For case of not HTML5, normally will get help with flash to accomplish such task